# jsgrid bound with mvc data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, jsgrid

I am trying to bind jsGrid with json data OR a list of objects..whatever is possible..

```
$("#mapsDiv").jsGrid({
        height: "auto",
        width: "100%",

        sorting: true,
        paging: false,
        autoload: true,
        data: students,
        controller: {
            loadData: function () {
                var d = $.Deferred();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("About", "Home")',
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function (response) {
                    d.resolve(response.value);
                });

                return d.promise();
            }
        },

        fields: [
            { name: "firstname", type: "text" },
            { name: "surname", type: "text"},
            {
                name: "birthdate", type: "text"
            },
            {
                name: "classname", type: "text"
            }
        ]
    });
```

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult About(){
...
return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

OR

```
public ActionResult About(){
...
return View(students);
}
```

in case of json, my web page shows a raw json string only, in case i return a list of student objects, everything else is on page but no grid.

What am i doing wrong?

On a side note, can i bind this grid with @Model as we do in markup?

Comment: Check in Network what is the response you getting. Check for casing of model properties. About "Side note" yes you can. After you bind data to a table just call jqgird function on that table.

Comment: i tried using var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.students)), which worked!! now how can i define a template so that it can dynamically add x number of columns in addition to the above 4 columns?

Comment: You need to add manually .

Comment: @Samra Not sure if my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44257219/4868839) can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue with not being able to manipulate json data and being stuck passing static data from applying a key to my data dictionary.

After looking around http://js-grid.com/docs/ this is an example of how I used a custom rowRenderer (that you could easily embed logic into) to process jsGrid data

My JS jsgrid code looks something like this

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({

data : [{ 'name' : 'Louise' , 'duties' : ['pranks', 'busing tables'] }, 
        { 'name' : 'Linda' , 'duties' : ['waiting tables', 'singing', 'comedic relief'] }],

rowRenderer: function(item, itemIndex) {
     var newRow = $('<tr>'); // create a new, empty HTML tr element

     let nameCell = $('<td>');
     let dutiesCell = $('<td>');
     let summaryCell = $('<td>');

     let nameCellData = item['name']
     let dutiesCellData = item['duties']
     let summaryCellData = 'This is row ' + itemIndex + ' of this grid. The name of the employee that this row is about is ' + item['name'] + ' and she has ' + item['duties'].length + ' duties at the family restaurant!';


     $(nameCell).append(document.createTextNode(nameCellData));
     $(dutiesCell).append(document.createTextNode(dutiesCellData));
     $(summaryCell).append(document.createTextNode(summaryCellData));


     $(newRow).append(nameCell);
     $(newRow).append(dutiesCell);
     $(newRow).append(summaryCell);

     return newRow;
},
```

..... (insert the rest of your jsgrid config here)

The main saving grace is the overlooked rowRenderer. From the docs, the function can use **item** which is used to iterate through the dictionaries in my example array, **itemIndex** is the row number in the jsGrid (which may be helpful for formatting later on), and I took advantage of this format to call my own keys on **item**. I hope this helps!

Comment: I stopped using jsGrid as we found solution with some other control but it seems like you found a solution so i am marking it as answer